# Пресечение двух списков по правилам кроссворда на python

Tags: python-3.x

Допустим есть 2 слова:

```
aristocracy
yesterday
```

И нужно найти, сколькими способами можно пересечь два слова по правилам кроссворда.

Входные данные: `aristocracy, yesterday`
Выходные: 8

> Пример:

[image]

Comment: Нужно написать вам готовый код или есть конкретный вопрос?

Comment: каждый символ первого слова сравниваете с каждым символом второго. при совпадении увеличиваете счётчик (изначально равный нулю) на единицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cross_count(w1, w2):
    res = 0
    common = set(w1) & set(w2)
    for c in common:
        res += max(w1.count(c), w2.count(c))
    return res
```

результат:

```
In [112]: cross_count('aristocracy', 'yesterday')
Out[112]: 8
```